# Need help making a page editable using PHP?

Tags: php, html

Can anyone help me fix the error in here I am trying to make the page editable through a PHP script. If anyone know how to do this or to fix this please help me my code is here:

The error I receive is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'of' (T_STRING) in /home/goaerox/public_html/monthadmin.php on line 28

> ```
> public function editAction(){
>     // Create an instance of form than read .phtml file and set content
>     $file_path        = APPLICATION_PATH.”potm”.html;
>     $file_content     = file_get_contents($file_path);
>     $this->view->form = new Admin_Form_LandingPage();
>     $this->view->form->setDefaults(array('landing_page' => $file_content));
>
>     // Check if we have permission to edit file
>     if(!is_writable($file_path)){
>         $this->view->form->landing_page->setAttrib('disabled', 'disabled');
>         $this->view->form->save->setAttrib('disabled', 'disabled');
>         My_Utilities::fmsg("You need to set <b>write permission(777)</b> for file $file_path.", 'error');
>         return;
>     }
>
>     // Write/Override existing .html page
>     if($this->_request->isPost() && $this->view->form->isValid($_POST)){
>         file_put_contents($file_path, $this->view->form->getValue('landing_page'));
>         My_Utilities::fmsg(‘Partner of the Month has saved successfully.');
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: what is the error you get

Comment: use chmod?? http://se1.php.net/chmod or am I missing something here?

Comment: @HaimEvgi The error I get is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'of' (T_STRING) in /home/goaerox/public_html/monthadmin.php on line 28

Comment: and on line 28 there would appear to be an extra "}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

```
 $file_path        = APPLICATION_PATH.”potm”.html;
```

looks wrong perhaps you meant soemthing like:

```
 $file_path        = APPLICATION_PATH . $potm . ".html";
```